# Getting array keys in Twig? (Symfony)

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig

Is it possible to get the key of an array in Twig (in Symfony)?

For example if I have an array of:

```
array(
'key1' => 'value1',
'key2' => 'value2',
);
```

Is it possible in Twig to print:

> key1: value1
>
> key2: value2

Thanks

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try following format:

```
{% for key, value in array %}
    {{ key }} - {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

More Information on **Offical Twig** about `Iterating over Keys and Values`

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/for.html#iterating-over-keys-and-values

Comment: This helped with my case. Much appreciated @Bora

Answer (score 25):

You can use the *keys* filter. The keys filter returns the keys of an array.

```
{% set keys = array|keys %}
```

or

```
{% for key in array|keys %}
   {{ key }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have this array: `person = ['name': 'John', 'age': '30']`, you can display the value of a specific key, like this:

```
<p> Name = {{ person.name}} </p>
<p> Age= {{ person.age}} </p>
```